# Moving Icons - Pixels

Tags: html, css, icons, pixel

I've been researching this for a while, but cannot find any solutions.

Here's my code

```
<p><iframe allowtransparency="true" scrolling="no" frameborder="no" src="https://w.soundcloud.com/icon/?url=http%3A%2F%2Fsoundcloud.com%2F&color=orange_white&size=32" style="width: 32px; height: 32px;"></iframe> <a href="LINK"target="_blank"><img src="http://2014.software-quality-days.com/uploads/RTEmagicC_facebook_02.png.png "/> </a></p>
```

If you copy and paste this code into the HTML area of this site: http://jsfiddle.net/T3Nnu/3/

If you look at the Facebook Icon, it is set a few pixels higher than the SoundCloud (Orange) icon. Is there any way that I can make it even / parallel with the SoundCloud (Orange) icon?

Answer (score 0):

change it with following:

```
<p>
    <iframe 
        allowtransparency="true" scrolling="no" frameborder="no" 
        src="https://w.soundcloud.com/icon/?url=http%3A%2F%2Fsoundcloud.com%2F&color=orange_white&size=32" 
        style="width: 32px; height: 32px;">
    </iframe>
    <a href="LINK"target="_blank">
        <img height="32px" width="32px" src="http://2014.software-quality-days.com/uploads/RTEmagicC_facebook_02.png.png "/>
    </a>
</p>
```

Because iframe height and width is 32px and image width and height is 34px.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this,  http://jsfiddle.net/T3Nnu/4/

```
<a href="http://soundcloud.com/" target="_blank">
<img src="https://w.soundcloud.com/icon/assets/images/orange_white_32-94fc761.png" style="width: 32px; height: 32px;"/>
</a>
<a href="http://fb.com" target="_blank"><img style="margin-top:10px" src="http://2014.software-quality-days.com/uploads/RTEmagicC_facebook_02.png.png "/>
</a>
```